# Is wolmanized wood different that just treated wood?

Tags: lumber, pressure-treated, decking

The title says it all, is wolmanized wood different that just treated wood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolmanized wood is a subsection of pressure treated wood. There are many different processes that fall in the preserved wood category and Wolmanized wood used a copper azole process. It is manufactured by Arch wood products.